# Still getting Audit Failures

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2019

I have a machine running at Digital Ocean that has been getting failed RDP login attempts.  I thought I had RDP Firewall rules set such that I should only allow connections from 3 IP's that I want to RDP from.  Have I set my firewalls up correctly?  Does anyone know why I would still be getting Failed Login attempts when my Firewall rule is in place?

The Remote Desktop -User Mode (TCP-in) and The Remote Desktop -User Mode (UDP-in) are both set to only allow Remote IP addresses in their scope tabs.
[Firewall Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEyeW.jpg)

Comment: Logon Type 3 (Network) is not an RDP logon attempt. Logon Type 10 (Remote Interactive) is an RDP logon attempt. Your problem is not with RDP. What network services are available on this machine? A website? Shared folders or printers?

Comment: @joeqwerty, yes, a website

Comment: @joeqwerty is there a way to tell which port they are hitting from the log? I have locked down 80,443 from the firewall to include only a certain list of IP's and they are still hitting my server with Audit Failures and I have no idea where they are trying to access.  Again, this is on a Digital Ocean Droplet and I don't have access to the router

Comment: Nevermind, I used wireshark and saw it was port 445 so I locked that down and I'm finally good to go without login attempts.  Thank you so much for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

@joeqwerty led me in the direction that it was port 445 SMB connections rather than RDP.  I was able to lock SMB down and the attacks stopped.